# Using a for loop to declare values in an array from image in resources

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

Using java for Android development.

I have an array that stores image resources. The image resources are named in numerical order (1.png, 2.png, etc). I would like to use a for loop to create the values in the array instead of declaring each value individually.

What I have tried:

```
 private int[] myArray = {R.drawable.r1, R.drawable.r2, etc};
```

What I would like to do:

```
 private int[] myArray;
 myArray = new int[50]
 for (i=0; i<50; i++) {
 myArray[i] = R.drawable. + "i"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this sort of thing is technically possible, but is prone to certain issues. The R class is dynamically generated. While its moderately predictable, if for some reason your generated values change it could completely break your code. However, if you were to do this it would look like this:

```
 private int[] myArray;
 myArray = new int[50];
 int id = R.drawable.firstImage;
 for (i=0; i<50; i++) {
    myArray[i] = id + i;
 }
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a document that discusses how resource id's are generated. By the way thank you, this is very helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure. I've done something similar but ultimately decided it wasn't safe and did something different. However, I wasn't dealing with 50+ id's. You might consider assigning a tag to each view using `view.setTag(object)` and then use `findViewWithTag(object)` to manage your views. If you assign an `Integer` object to each view you could "index" them in this way. Then you wouldn't need the array.